# Machine-Learning classification results too good to be true?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

Sorry about all the text, but I think the background of this project would help:

I've been working on a binary classification project. The original dataset consisted of about 28,000 of class 0 and 650 of class 1, so it was very highly imbalanced. I was given an under- and over-sampled dataset to work with that was 5,000 of each class (class 1 instances were simply duplicated 9 times). After training models on this and getting sub-par results (an AUC of about .85, but it needed to be better) I started wondering if these sampling techniques were actually a good idea, so I took the original highly imbalanced dataset out again. I plugged it right into a default GradientBoostClassifier, trained it on 80% of the data and 
I immediately got something like this:

```
Accuracy:
0.997367035282
AUC:
.9998
Confusion Matrix:
[[5562    7]
 [   8  120]]
```

Now, I know a high accuracy can be an artefact of the imbalanced classes, but I did not expect an AUC like this or that kind of performance! So I am very confused and feel there must be something an error in my technique somewhere...but I have no idea what it is. I've tried a couple different classifiers too and gotten similar levels of ridiculously good performance. I didn't leave the class labels in the data array and the training data is COMPLETELY different than the testing data. Each observation has about 130 features too, so this isn't a simple classification. It very much seems like something is wrong, I'm sure the classifier cannot be this good. Could there be anything else I am overlooking? Any other common pitfalls people run into like this with unbalanced data?

I can provide the code, probability plots,example datapoints etc. if they would be helpful, but I didn't want this to get too long for now. Thanks to anybody who can help!

Comment: Question probably belongs on [Stats Exchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: A classifier that predicted all class 0 would get ~98% accuracy according to your numbers. The skew is so large that it dominates measurements and your biggest confusion is caused by changing how you take your metrics. You simply cannot compare AUC measured on a re-balanced set and one taken on this raw set, so you have no idea here which is better. Decide what you want to measure first regarding your objective and stick with it - regardless of how you train.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks, I'm a little confused though. What do you mean when you say decide what I want to measure and stick with it? I'm not sure if this is what you are talking about but I've been trying to maximize the true-positive rate for a 20% false positive rate, so that's why I've been so interested in the AUC. This project is for disease diagnosis, so the true-positive rate is pretty important and that's why I'm less concerned about the overall accuracy.

Comment: But you measured your AUC on a *different* hold out set . . . the measurement of performance needs to be on the exact same test.

Comment: I guess you are saying I'm not being consistent with the distribution of data I'm putting into the training and testing set for those two situations? But my question isn't really about the first situation. I'm more wondering how realistic it is for just a default classifier to give results that are this good on such a complex (6000 x 130) data set. So I don't really care about that kind of consistency I think, I'm just trying to see if this way of slicing and sampling the data I have can lead to better performance of my classifiers overall.

Comment: No I am only referring to the specific data you put into the test set. It doesn't matter so much what you put into the training set. You absolutely do care about this kind of consistency if you want to reject the rebalanced approach for the "default" approach because you think it is somehow better. Yes, it could actually be better, but what you have done does not show that. The 0.85 and 0.99 that you are comparing (in a kind of absolutist way) are not in fact comparable, and 0.99 result is not meaningful on its own

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy may not be the best performance metric in your case, maybe you can think of using precision,recall and F1 score, and  perform some debugging via learning curves, over fitting detection, etc.

Comment: Right, well I'm not really looking at the accuracy score too much. I can see just from the confusion matrix that it is a really good classifier, I just don't know if it is realistic for it to be doing that well or if it could be indicative of some kind of error.

Comment: If the dataset is easily seperable and you are using 80 % of the dataset for training and there are only 2 classes it is not unusual to get really good results.

Comment: @MrDinkleburg run cross-validation.